# Getting Null when trying to Call Servlet action using javaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

Well i have one login From and i am trying to call that login action means servlet using java script but when i trying to print that data in servlet post request i am getting null values. can some one tell me what i am doing wrong.?

my jsp page:-

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function facebookcheck() {
        alert('function called');

        var email = document.getElementById("login").value;
        alert('Email check:'+emailcheck(email));
        alert("Email:"+document.getElementById("login").value);
        if (document.getElementById("login").value = "") {
            alert('Please Enter Your Facebook Email');
            return false;

        }if (emailcheck(email) == false) {
            alert('Please Enter Valid Email');
            return false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("password").value = "") {
            alert('Please Enter Your Facebook Password');
            return false;
        }

        //document.getElementById("param_ID").value = x;
        document.aform.action = "ServletCall";
        // calling servlet action 
        document.aform.submit();
    }

    function emailcheck(email){
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div
            style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: auto; max-width: 480px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 2px solid #0361A8; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #0361A8; margin: 50px auto auto;">
            <div
                style="background: #0361A8; border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px; padding: 15px;">
                <span
                    style="font-family: verdana, arial; color: #D4D4D4; font-size: 1.00em; font-weight: bold;">Enter
                    your login and password</span>
            </div>
            <div style="background:; padding: 15px">

                <form method="post" action="ServletCall" name="aform">
                    <table class='center'>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Facebook Email:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="login" name="login"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Facebook Password:</td>
                            <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><input type="button" value="Login Facebook" onclick='facebookcheck()'></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=2>Forget Your Password Click <a
                                href="https://www.authpro.com/auth/deluxe/?action=lost">here</a>!
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=2>Not member yet? Click <a
                                href="netfilmes.bl.ee/registro">here</a> to register.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

my servelet action :-


package com.facebook.action;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/ServletCall")
public class ServletCall extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public ServletCall() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            System.out.println("Servlet Called");



            System.out.println("Email :" + request.getAttribute("login"));
            System.out.println("Password:" + request.getAttribute("password"));


            System.out.println("Email :" + request.getParameter("login"));
            System.out.println("Password:" + request.getParameter("password"));

            request.getRequestDispatcher("Error.jsp")
                    .forward(request, response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

out put that i am getting.

```
Servlet Called
Email :null
Password:null
Email :null
Password:null
Email :
Password:
```

can any body suggent me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: you have already mentioned action in <form/> tag then why again document.aform.action = "ServletCall"; ?

Comment: @www.sblog.in u can make it comment to still its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can not work.
You are using single equal sign instead of two in your checks:

```
if (document.getElementById("login").value = "") {
```

and

```
if (document.getElementById("password").value = "") {
```

always return true since you are doing an assignment and not a check. So, you return false, and so you should not be able to submit your form. Moreover, you set your two fields to empty value.

Please, check your code: it might be different than the one you put here.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, error is in your javascript function so rest of your code not executed.

```
 if (document.getElementById("login").value = "") {
            alert('Please Enter Your Facebook Email');
            return false;

        }if (emailcheck(email) == false) {
            alert('Please Enter Valid Email');
            return false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("password").value = "") {
            alert('Please Enter Your Facebook Password');
            return false;
        }
```

you have to use "==" to compare two things.

second thing just use $(#formname).submit(); to submit your form thats it.

Comment: i got ans bro. but any ways +1 for your ans too and its right. :)

Comment: `$(#formname).submit()` is wrong. You have to encapsulate it with quotes : `$("#formname").submit()`. And it is not standard JS, so it will not work (unless jQuery is loaded in the page).

Comment: ya i know ipratlong i assumed that jquery is loaded and about #formname is common thing which all know that attribute should be in quotes. btw sorry for that.